# Problema al crear una paginación con numeración utilizando react y node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, paginacion

Acabo de terminar de realizar mi paginación del lado del servidor y funciona correctamente: la misma me retorna lo siguiente:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "nuevo titulo",
            "subtitle": "",
            "body": "",
            "image": "******",
            "createdAt": "2021-10-09T01:49:38.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-10-09T01:49:38.000Z"
        }    ],
    "count": 11,
    "pages": 2
}
```

lo que hice fue crear una sencilla paginación con previous y next,  aprovechando que utilizo react query para hacer el fetch:

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1)
let { isLoading, isError, data, error, isFetching}:any = useQuery(["posts", page], ()=> PostService(page), { keepPreviousData : true });

if(isLoading){
  return (  
      <Center>
        <Spinner size="xl" color="blue" thickness="5px" />
      </Center>
      )
}else if(isError){
  return(
<Center>
        <h4>Ocurrió un problema : {error}</h4>
  </Center>
  )
}
return (
        //Paginación
        <Container maxWidth="container.md" p={{base:"0px"}}>
        <NewList datas={data.posts}/>
        <Center mb="10px">
        <Button
          onClick={() => setPage(old => Math.max(old - 1, 1))}
          disabled={page === 1}
        >
          previus
        </Button>{' '}
       
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
         setPage(old => old + 1)
          }}
          // Disable the Next Page button until we know a next page is available
          disabled={page >= data.pages}
        >
          next
        </Button>
        
      </Center>
        </Container>
      
    )
    
}
```

Lo que necesito es a partir de ahora como realizar una paginación con numeración , si alguien me pudiese ayudar, estaria muy agradecido.
La solución que encontré es la siguiente (pero aun asi no me parece la más optima):
(data.pages es la cantidad de paginas que tengo y esta información me la  proporciona la api en la respuesta)

```
{[...Array(data.pages).keys()].map((i)=>{
          i= page;
        return (
        <li>{i}</li>
        )
        })
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado / investigado? Tal como está tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, y requiere muchas explicaciones. Además, existen diversas formas de lograr lo que pides. Saludos

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con mi solución , pero no creo que sea la más optima ya que debo colocarle algunos condicionales, quisiera saber si existe algun tipo de patron o una solucion al tema de la numeración